# $1$-Lipschitz $f:[0,1]^k\to[0,1]^n$ With Maximally Dense Image

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, lipschitz-functions, packing-problem

Is there anything known about which $1$-Lipschitz functions $$f:(X:=[0,1]^m)\to(Y:=[0,1]^n)$$ for $m$ < $n$ fill the codomain maximally dense, i.e. I want to minimize $\sup_{y\in Y}d(y, f(X))$ where $d(a, B)$ is defined as $\inf_{b\in B}d(a, b)$ and we use Euclidean distance for $d$.  What about $K$-Lipschitz functions for $K\neq 1$ (or equivalently $X:=[0,K]^m$)?

If this is too hard to answer, what about $f$ being of the form $$y_i=\sum_j\sin^*(a_j x_j+b_j)$$ where $\sin^*(x):=(\sin(x)+1)/2$?

Comment: I've removed the tag *recreational-mathematics* because this problem does not fall under what most anyone would consider to be recreational mathematics. It may be something **you're doing** for recreational purposes -- and in that sense, [my answers here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780) are the same for me -- it's not useful to classify it as recreational mathematics. Indeed, any area of math would probably be classified as recreational mathematics if we go by that criterion.

Comment: I see, that makes sense!  I was just using this tag because I couldn't locate the question in a specific field of mathematics.  And yes, $d$ being Euclidean distance @student91, I just made an edit!

Comment: In the case $k=1, n=2$, that would be the line from left to right, right?  Because I believe that in this case the centered C-shape (like a square with one side missing) with the four corners at distance $1/2$ from the corners of $[0, 1]^2$ would be of length less than $1$ but still has each point in $[0,1]^2$ at distance at most $1/2$.  So it would seem that one could add something to this C-shape to make it of length $1$ so that this maximal distance to $[0,1]^2$ becomes less than $1/2$.

Comment: hmmm yes I see. Generalising this approach would give $\frac{2^{n-k}-1}{2^{n-k+1}-1}\sqrt{n-k}$ which is always smaller than $\frac{\sqrt{n-k}}{2}$.

Comment: The optimal distance I found by hand for the $k=1,n=2$ case is a C-shape with the "back" of length $\frac12$ and the "prongs" of length $\frac14$, which gives a minimal distance of $\frac{\sqrt{13}}8$, which is smaller than both $\frac12$ (My initial guess) or $\frac{\sqrt2}{3}$ (A C with sizes $\frac13$ for all segments).

Comment: Thanks!  Can you formulate this as an answer, so I can accept it and mark the question as answered?

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment here about recreational mathematics, for those interested I just now came across the recently asked question [*When is a question 'recreational'?*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35502/13130) in meta-MSE. One of the answers is especially thorough. (I only look at meta-MSE once every few weeks, which is why I only now became aware of that question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything known about which $1$-Lipschitz functions $$f:(X:=[0,1]^m)\to(Y:=[0,1]^n)$$ for $m$ < $n$ fill the codomain maximally dense, i.e. I want to minimize $\sup_{y\in Y}d(y, f(X))$ where $d(a, B)$ is defined as $\inf_{b\in B}d(a, b)$ and we use Euclidean distance for $d$.  What about $K$-Lipschitz functions for $K\neq 1$ (or equivalently $X:=[0,K]^m$)?

I know a good lower bound $n=2$ and $m=1$, which is as follows:

- For $K\leq\frac12$, consider the function $f\colon [0,K]\to[0,1]^2$ given by $f(t)=\left(\frac{1-K}{2}+t,\frac12\right)$. It has a maximal distance $\frac12\sqrt{2-2K+K^2}$, which I believe is maximal for this range of $K$.
- For $\frac12\le K\le\frac32$, consider the function given by $f(t)=\begin{cases}\left(\frac14,\frac{5-2K}8+t\right)&t\le\frac{2K-1}4,\\\left(\frac{1-K}2+t,\frac{2K-1}{8}\right)&\frac{2K-1}4\le t\le\frac{2K+3}4,\\\left(\frac34,t-\frac{2K+7}8\right)&\frac{2K+3}4\le t\le K.\end{cases}$
- For $\frac32\le K\le\frac{15}4$, set $a=\frac{6-K}9$ and $b=\frac{2K-3}{18}$ (such that $a+b=\frac12$ and $K=12a+3b$) and consider the function given by $$f(t)=\begin{cases}\left(\frac14-a+t,\frac14-a\right)&0\le t\le a\\\left(\frac14+a,\frac14-a+(t-a)\right)&a\le t\le 2a\\\left(\frac14+a-(t-2a),\frac14+a\right)&2a\le t\le 3a\\\left(\frac14-a,\frac14+a+(t-3a)\right)&3a\le t\le4a+b\\\left(\frac14-a+(t-4a-b),\frac34+a\right)&4a+b\le t\le5a+b\\\left(\frac14+a,\frac34+a-(t-5a-b)\right)&5a+b\le t\le 6a+b\\\left(\frac14+a+(t-6a-b),\frac34-a\right)&6a+b\le t\le 6a+2b\\\left(\frac34-a,\frac34-a+(t-6a-2b)\right)&6a+2b\le t\le 7a+2b\\\left(\frac34-a+(t-7a-2b),\frac34+a\right)&7a+2b\le t\le8a+2b\\\left(\frac34+a,\frac34+a-(t-8a-2b)\right)&8a+2b\le t\le 9a+3b\\\left(\frac34+a-(t-9a-3b),\frac14+a\right)&9a+3b\le t\le 10a+3b\\\left(\frac34-a,\frac14+a-(t-10a-3b)\right)&10a+3b\le t\le 11a+3b\\\left(\frac34-a+(t-11a-3b),\frac14-a\right)&11a+3b\le t\le K.\end{cases}$$ Note that for $K=\frac32$ this is the first iteration of the [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve), and for $K=\frac{15}4$ this is the second iteration. It has minimal distance $(\frac14-\frac a2)\sqrt2$. You can see in a drawing that this is not the *precise* minimum, because e.g. the distance to $(\frac12,\frac12)$ or $(0,\frac12)$ is strictly smaller than the minimal distance, so some length can be taken away to make distances smaller.
- For larger $K$, interpolate the Hilbert curve in a similar fashion (see also [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hilbert_curve_3.svghttps://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hilbert_curve_3.svg)).

For different values of $m$, while keeping $n=1$ you should end up with space filling curves of $m$-dimensional space when $K\to\infty$. For $K=1$ I believe the first-iteration Hilbert curve is still optimal though.

When changing $n$ and keeping $K=1$, I believe your best bet is taking a solution for a 1-dimensional domain and just extending it in the other directions. When $K$ becomes larger, you could change the domain by finding a map $[0,K]^m\hookrightarrow[0,1]^{m-1}\times[0,K']$ with $K'\ge K$ and then still doing the same.

> If this is too hard to answer, what about $f$ being of the form $$y_i=\sum_j\sin^*(a_j x_j+b_j)$$ where $\sin^*(x):=(\sin(x)+1)/2$?

I don't think this makes things simpler. Proving something for the current case is hard enough.